# Adwords Call Tracking number replace with Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-ads-api, google-tag-manager

I am trying to setup Google Call Tracking with GTM following this [Definitive Guide](https://www.redflymarketing.com/blog/adwords-call-tracking-guide-gtm/)

I have the script from Adwords and pasted in GTM Tag properly. But the function

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {_googWcmGet('number', 'X-XXX-XXX-XXXX');});
```

is not clear to me. I tried pasting it exactly but doesn't work. So my question is what should I replace it to follow my needs.

The number mentioned in Adwords Call Extension is of format 020 12345678

The number mentioned in the website is of format +44 (0) 20 - 12345678 And is under the

```
<span class="number">+44 (0) 20 – 12345678</span>
```

as mentioned in the tutorial. But still its not replacing the original number with google number. I am not able to understand what to replace the XXX in the function with.

For testing I have already tried by clicking the actual google ad

Comment: To exclude the obvious, do you use jQuery at all in your website (the function you copy/pasted relies on the jQuery javascript library). As for the XXX, your tutorial says "where the X’s represent your regular/default office number".

Comment: Yeah javascript is definitely included... yeah X represents the default number but i tried all X as well as both the number formats but it still does not replace the original number